# In TYPO3 9.5.5 Version PageTitleSeparator not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I am using TYPO3 9.5.5 version and in setup.typoscript file I am using this code to separator my pagetitle to sitetitle.

```
    config{
      pageTitleFirst = 1
      pageTitleSeparator = -
      pageTitleSeparator.noTrimWrap = | | |
    }
```

Although My PageTtitle is correct and it comes first after that site title and my website uses this default separator |. But I want - this separator to separate sitetitle. I did not understand why my these easy line of code is not working.

Answer (score -1):

this works fine for me with 9.5.7

```
config {
    noPageTitle = 2
    htmlSpecialChars = 1
    pageTitleFirst = 1
    pageTitleSeparator = -
    pageTitleSeparator.noTrimWrap = | | |
}
```